# Generate artifact without parent directory

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Following is the Maven assembly plugin details from pom.xml of my project:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/prj-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>myArtifact</finalName>
                    <outputDirectory>target/package</outputDirectory>
                    <workDirectory>target/assembly/work</workDirectory>
                    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

All works fine and artifacts are generated but problem is that a parent directory also gets generated with name of artifact. So artifact structure looks something like:

```
myArtifact.tar.gz
              |_myArtifact [This is the parent directory]
                        |_ myfolder
                                  |_myfiles
```

What i want is

```
myArtifact.tar.gz              
                |_ myfolder
                          |_myfiles
```

How can i achieve this?

EDIT:

Following are descriptor [prj-assembly.xml] details:

```
<assembly>
  <id>deploy</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>src/main/scripts/f1.sh</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>false</filtered>
      <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
      <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>src/main/scripts/install.sh</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>false</filtered>
      <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
      <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>src/main/scripts/activate.sh</source>
      <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>false</filtered>
      <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
      <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    </file>
  </files>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Can you show your assembly descriptor? Why are you using an old maven-assembly-plugin version (current: 2.4).

Comment: @khmarbaise: Added the descriptor, see my edit. And no real reason to use 2.3 , we can use 2.4. But i dont think it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is you didn't add the

```
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
```

in your assembly descriptor. The includeBaseDirectory does not belong to the configuration area of the plugin, cause the [goal single does not has any kind of this configuration item](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html).

Apart from that why are you changing the values of:

```
<outputDirectory>target/package</outputDirectory>
<workDirectory>target/assembly/work</workDirectory>
```

Comment: "outputDirectory" and "workDirectory" values have been changed just for having a cleaner approach. No real reason as such.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your assembly descriptor:

```
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
```